# Intercept web socket call at frontend being made from an external library?

Tags: javascript, angular, web, websocket

I have this requirement where in my Angular app, I have another **Angular Module**, let's say, **UtilModule**, in the **imports** section of my main **NgModule**. **UtilModule** is imported from a node_module like so:-

```
import {UtilModule} from "utillib";
```

**UtilModule** has various services and one of them is a websocket service which forms a websocket connection at a url formed using `window.location` + hardcoded string value.

My main component extends a class (again part of **UtilModule**) which uses this websocket service.

Now I cannot change the value of url being used by the websocket service. But I don't want to point to this url, instead I want to point it to a particular url where my websocket backend is actually located.

How can I achieve this? Possibly some kind of request interceptor at frontend itself which redirects it to the required url?

Answer (score 0):

Does the library export its service directly?

Without seeing the actual lib, I'm just guessing here...

You could

1. create a new service that extends theirs,
2. try and change the uri in your new one
3. then in your Module's providers you can swap their service with yours using the `useClass` option

Depending on how you use the service (if you import it directly, or if the library internally uses it), this may or may not work

Comment: Hey thanks for taking time to answer. I found a method in the service without extending it and since it was a singleton, I was able to use it to create a new websocket connection over required url.